# android studio build.gradle error in building

Tags: android, android-studio

android studio build.gradle file error nothing in android block is there and it compiles and doesnt give error in building.[image] All the parts of the android {} body say 'No candidates found for method call compileSdk' unable to fix with simple restarts, rebuilds, or invalidations. Hovering over android this pops up[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are misspellings in your file:

- `minSdkVersion` instead of `minSdk`, more info [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/sdk-versions#minsdkversion)
- `targetSdkVersion` instead of `targetSdk`, more info [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/sdk-versions#targetsdkversion)